# List to tuple with index

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of `int`s:
 
`len = [140, 129, 118, 140, ...]`

I would like to convert these into a list of tuples whilst using their respective index's

So the result would output `[(0,140),(1,129),(2,118),(3,140)...]`

I have attempted to do this with this snippet:

```
for i, val in enumerate(len):
    res = [(i,val) for val in len]
```

However, this assigns the final index value to each tuple and outputs:
`[(85, 140), (85, 129), (85, 118), (85, 140)]`

Comment: Please don't name your variables using built-in names like `len` - you won't be able to get the length of your list by writing `len(...)` in that case.

Comment: `[(i,L[i]) for i in range(len(L))]` where L is the list name.

Comment: that's already what enumerate does for you, you just want `list(enumerate(data))`

Comment: @Mathieu why wouldn't you use enumerate?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Agree. I just didn't think about it.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `list(enumerate(some_list))`.

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) generates tuples, and calling `list` pulls all the values from that generator into a list.

Any other steps you take (like a list comprehension or tuple unpacking) serve only to slow down the process.

---

The reason for the results you were seeing is because you replace `res` completely in every loop, and `res` only includes the index of the iteration.

In the first iteration, you had `i=0` and `val=140`, and your list comprehension set `res` to `[(0, 140), (0, 129), (0, 118), ...]`. The second iteraton had `i=1` and `val=129`, and you set `res` to `[(1, 140), (1, 129), ...]`. Each loop, you just replaced `res` with a new list using the index from the loop, so at the end, `res` was using the last index from the loop (85).

---

Also, as noted in [kaya3's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382038/python-list-to-tuple-with-index/60382068#comment106814966_60382038), you shouldn't use built-in names like `len` (or `list`) as variable names, because it will prevent you from using the builtins normally.

```
len = [140, 129, 118, ...]
print(len(len))  # error: len is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will give you the desired output.

`final_output = [(i, lis[i]) for i in range(len(lis))]`